# Receive Email address instead of Name with POI from *.msg-File [Java]

Tags: java, email, apache-poi, msg, read-data

i wrote a small java programm which extract the names,email address, subject, bodytext from a *.msg by using POI 3.15 and writes it to an excel sheet.

By reading the MAPIMessage API Documentation i saw:

```
getDisplayFrom() --> Gets the display value of the "FROM" line of the outlook message This is not the actual address that was sent from but the formated display of the user name.
```

Now i would like to get the email address from sender instead of his stored nickname.

Just btw - for receiving the Emailaddress of all "to"-persons you can use getRecipientEmailAddress().

Any suggestions how to deal with it?

thanks in advance

Edit:
I just noticed you can use the first element of getHeaders() to get the Return-Path - which is the emailaddress of "from". kinda dirty way ... so my question is still up to be answered ;)

Comment: I found this discussion about the problem. Looks like there's a hacky solution coming to Apache's library soon. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1865

Answer (score 2):

I don't know in previous versions, but in 3.17 you can get it from main chunks.

```
MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage("email.msg");

Chunks mainChunks = msg.getMainChunks();
StringChunk emailFromChunk = mainChunks.getEmailFromChunk();
String emailFrom = emailFromChunk.getValue();
```